80/90's TV mini series with Jack Scalia
I remember a TV miniseries, in 80's or possibly the 90's, staring Jack Scalia, where he charms three vacationing women in Latin America. Their gullibility lands them in a latin american prison on drug charges.
Latter, the past behind them, the three women have become successful, but after one of them spots Scalia in an American city, they join together to get revenge. In the end they imprison him in their basement, to afford him the same experience they underwent many years ago. 
I think one of the women was played by Sheila McCarthy.
Can anyone identify it ?

Ring of Scorpio (1991) @ IMDB
Synopsis

Three women (Catherine Oxenberg, Catherine Goodall, Linda Cropper) plot revenge against a drug dealer (Jack Scalia) who scammed them into working in his operations.

I was wrong about Shelia McCarthy.

You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out this answer a little more.
